# Boot from virtual usb drive in qemu-kvm

Tags: debian, usb, qemu, bootable

I want to create multi-bootable USB with GRUB2. But I don't want to use physical USB stick to experiment with.

How can I create virtual USB to play with it as it is real device using qemu? I want to boot guest machine from it, setup GRUB to it from guest OS and so on.

Later, I want to be able to take the virtual image and copy it to my real USB stick. How could I do that? Perhaps with `if=usb_image.vmdk of=/dev/sdx`?

Comment: No longer working, I think the parameters in KVM/QEMU have drastically changed. I've seen these exact same notes various places on the web, but they're quite obsolete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using an abstraction layer such as `libvirt`? If so then simply add a disk image file as a USB Disk.

If you're running `kvm`/`qemu` directly, then the man page (`man kvm` or `man qemu`) provides the answers:

> USB options:
>
> -usb Enable → the USB driver (will be the default soon)
>
> -usbdevice devname → Add the USB device devname.
>
> disk:[format=format]:file → Mass storage device based on file. The
>   optional format argument will be used rather than detecting the
>   format. Can be used to specify "format=raw" to avoid interpreting an
>   untrusted format header.

So, something like this should work

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=8000 of=usb.img    # Create the usb disk image
kvm ... -usb -usbdevice disk:raw:usb.img      # Start kvm/qemu
```

Later, you can run `dd if=usb.img bs=1M of=/dev/sdX`, but you should make sure your `/dev/sdX` really is the USB device! You'll also need to make your virtual image the same size as your stick (or smaller). Remember a 1GB stick is only 10^9 bytes, not 2^31 bytes.

Comment: Ok, I have virt-manager installed. Now I create virtual machine and try to add USB storage to it. I have options "vdi, cow, vmdk, etc." of type. But how i will dump my USB Image to real USB device? **dd if=usb_image.vmdk of=/dev/sdx** will work?

Comment: @Neka use type "raw". You said you wanted to use a virtual USB device instead of a real one, but you can use a real USB device if that's what you want.

Comment: I know, but i want to experiment with virtual, and create real one from this result, because now I have no stick to play with